# Replicate mean by group with model

Tags: r

I would like to replicate the result of simple calculation of the mean value per group using a statistical model in `R`.

Here is data I'm dealing with:

```
      EXIST    DATE VAR1 VAR2
    1     0 10/2015    6    4
    2     0 01/2016    6    4
    3     0 01/2014    5    4
    4     1 05/2015    5    4
    5     0 11/2015    6    4
```

Where `VAR1`, `VAR2` are integers 1:8 (groups/or levels), and `EXIST` = (0,1)

I simply calculate the mean per variable:

```
ag <- data.frame(as.matrix(aggregate(EXIST ~ VAR1 + VAR2, 
                                     data = dat, function(x) c(mean = mean(x)))))
```

Now I would like to replicate this with model (i.e. `lm` or `glm`, etc) and obtain the same results as with `aggregate`.

Hence I would have rate of the 16 values (VAR1 1:8 and VAR 1:8).

Here is my attempt:

```
tmp <- with(d,
        by(d, VAR1,
           function(x) lm(EXIST ~ VAR2 + VAR1 , data = dat)))
```

I was told that the model should be `lm(EXIST ~ VAR1 * VAR2, data=dat)`

So how I go about replicating the `aggregate function` that calculates the mean per each factor of variable? (why asking? Well, I would like to know how to do it with model).

Comment: the results of `aggregate` are the means of all *combinations* of `VAR1` and `VAR2` (`nrow(ag)` is 64 ...)

Comment: Ben you are right! I think I'm confusing everyone here myself included. The thing is that I do not have now the data available (to output the aggregate calc.) so I'm wrongly remembering it could be indeed 64. Your solution you have posted was correct indeed.

Comment: OK, undeleting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work a little harder to get R to treat each group separately: the relevant formula is `VAR1:VAR2-1` (include only the interaction  `:`, not the main effects: `VAR1*VAR2` corresponds to `VAR1+VAR2+VAR1:VAR2`; use `-1` to remove the intercept from the model).

Sample data:

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(EXIST=rbinom(1000,size=1,prob=0.3),
                 VAR1=factor(sample(1:8,size=1000,replace=TRUE)),
                 VAR2=factor(sample(1:8,size=1000,replace=TRUE)))
```

Note that you need your grouping variables to be factors.

Fit model and extract coefficients:

```
head(coef(lm(EXIST~VAR1:VAR2-1,data=dd)))
## VAR11:VAR21 VAR12:VAR21 VAR13:VAR21 VAR14:VAR21 VAR15:VAR21 VAR16:VAR21 
## 0.2666667   0.2307692   0.5714286   0.1176471   0.3846154   0.1333333
```

Check the first group:

```
mean(subset(dd,VAR1=="1" & VAR2=="1")$EXIST)  ## 0.266667
```